# Bias no-choice option and linear attributes

Tags: r, statistics

At the moment I am analysing survey data using Bayesian estimation in R (bayesm package)

For my analysis, I have included a no-choice option that is coded as a series of zeros. However, I also have a price attribute. This price attribute has three levels but I would like to treat it as a linear attribute to calculate the willingness-to-pay.

The issue is that the zero values of the no-choice options act like 'real' values for the linear price leading to bias in my estimates.

Example data:

[image]

Anyone familiar with this issue and/or workarounds?

Comment: I am not really sure what you are asking, but I *think* that you want to treat the price attribute as a binary variable. If this is the case then one-hot encoding might be a good solution for you. You would add a column that is 1 for "paid" and 0 for "not paid" and use that variable instead of the price attribute. Here is an explanation of one-hot encoding: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/38194/53760

Comment: Thank you for input. What I actually want to do is keep the price attribute as a linear variable. However, for the no-choice alternative (NoneOpt = 1) the zero is then considered as a linear variable as well. This leads to bias in the estimations according to existing literature

Comment: Interesting question, but it's off topic for SO. Try stats.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: You are right, I'll do that.